# How can I go about reading a specific line/lines from html in R?

Tags: r

For instance, Here is an extraction of the HTML code for the second-highest grossing movie

```
<tr bgcolor="#f4f4ff"><td align="center"><font size="2">2</font></td>
<td><font size="2"><a href="/movies/?id=titanic.htm"><b>Titanic</b></a></font></td>
```

How to find the line that has the movie title in it with using gregexpr?

Comment: You can use `XML::xmlValue()`.  Specifically, `getNodeSet(htmlParse(x), "//b", fun = xmlValue)` where `x` is the html file/url

Comment: How about not violating Box Office Mojo's Terms of Service while you're at it: _"Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this Site, except with our express written consent."_

Comment: I don't think it would be a violation of that TOS to attempt extracting from a single specific page, but I do not think that a particular page on that website has been identified, nor is an example presented that would support an effort at a coded answer. I have not visited that named website but that excerpt from the TOS doesn't say that you could not use the "show source" option from a browser. Nor did I find that exact code at the first listed hit on a search for the second line.

Comment: I tried to find the consistent code related to the movie title in a page like below. ##href="/movies/?id=titanic.htm"><b>Titanic</b></a></font></td>
In the case, I worked like expr <- '\\/movies\\/\\?id=.*\\.htm"><b>(.*)<\\/b>'
 
grep (expr, html page, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
unlist(regmatches (html page, gregexpr (expr, html page, perl=TRUE)))